# Selenium scraping div table, getting duplicate rows

Tags: pandas, selenium, web-scraping

I wrote a script that scrolls through an infinitely loading table on a site and scrapes the entries, but instead of being a  the entire thing is made up of  elements. I can't scroll through and then scrape since new elements are loaded as it scrolls (shows about 6-8 at a time), so it scrolls, scrapes, appends to a dataframe, then repeats. It works great for the first few hundred rows, then it starts to get duplicate rows. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
    def scrapenotis():
    driver.get("NOTIFICATIONS");
    WebDriverWait(driver, 120).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.vue-recycle-scroller__item-view")));

    tbltitles = ["Datetime","Username","User Link","Description","Category","Desc Link"];
    
    tablelist = [];
    starttime = datetime.now()
    while driver.title == "WEBSITE TITLE":
        try:
            # gets list of all entries
            entries = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.vue-recycle-scroller__item-view");

            if len(entries) == 0:
                break;
            
            # iterates through entries
            for x in entries:
                    # checking for those elements that persist for some ungodly reason
                    if x.get_attribute("style") == "transform: translateY(-9999px);":
                        continue;
                    #each entry is 83 pixels long with about 6 on screen at a time
                    driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, 300);");
                    # entries need to load after scroll, they load twice within a second(?)
                    time.sleep(1.5);

                    # datedesc = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='content']/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div[1]//div/div/div[5]/span/span").get_attribute("title");
                    datedesc = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.b-notifications__list__item__actions__item.g-date span").get_attribute("title");
                    username = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.b-username-wrapper div.g-user-name").text;
                    userlink = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.b-username-wrapper a").get_attribute("href");
                    description = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.b-notifications__list__item__text div.g-truncated-text").text;

                    #sorting them out for categories
                    if "ubscribed" in description:
                        cat = "New Sub";
                        desclink = "N/A";
                    elif "iked your" in description:
                        cat = "Like";
                        desclink = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.b-notifications__list__item__text div.g-truncated-text a").get_attribute("href");
                    elif "restarted their monthly subscription" in description:
                        cat = "Sub Renewal";
                        desclink = "N/A";
                    elif "purchased your" in description:
                        cat = "Purchase";
                        desclink = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.b-notifications__list__item__text div.g-truncated-text a").get_attribute("href");
                    elif any(x in description for x in ["eplied","esponded"]):
                        cat = "Comment";
                        desclink = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.b-notifications__list__item__text div.g-truncated-text a").get_attribute("href");
                    elif "tip" in description:
                        cat = "Tip";
                        desclink = "N/A";

                    dict1 = [datedesc,username,userlink,description,cat,desclink];
                    tablelist.append(dict1);
            #specify stop time in seconds
            if (datetime.now()-starttime).seconds >= 14400: #3600(1 hour) * 4 = 14400
                break;
        except:
            break

            

    #convert list to df
    msgbox(tablelist);
    df = pd.DataFrame(tablelist,columns=tbltitles);
    df.drop_duplicates(subset=tbltitles, inplace=True, keep='first');
    #save to csv
    path = filesavebox("Save your updated data file","","",["*.txt","*.csv"]);
    if path == None:
        return;
    df.to_csv(path + ".csv");
```

Comment: Can you provide us the url of the site and the whole code?

Comment: I cannot unfortunately :(

and the only other code besides this block are some easygui lines and a call for this method. I'm between a rock and a hard place lol